# How do I use ProcessStartInfo to run a batch file?

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, processstartinfo

But it doesn't work -meaning the java code is not executed.
Although the batch file runs fine when clicked in Windows explorer or when run in command line ..

Since this works fine when the batch file is a single DOS command, I think this is somehow related to the fact that the Java code needs ~20 minutes to run.
I'm using the following code

```
var si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.FileName = batchFileName;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(si);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `UseShellExecute` to true, so it loads cmd.exe to run the batch file.

Comment: Or, if you *really* don't want to use ShellExecute, instead run `cmd /C batchFileName.bat`.

Comment: Lucas - how should this be run ? Using ProcessStartInfo or something else?

Comment: You could run "cmd.exe" using ProcessStartInfo, passing "/C batchFileName.bat" as the command line.

Comment: I tried that and doesn't seem to be working for me (I'm not running as Admin and don't have Admin rights. I'm going to try first directly now

Answer (score 1):

As Lucas Jones mentioned in the comments, if you don't want to use ShellExecute, do it like this:

```
string fullBatPath = @"C:\path with space\file.bat";

var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"cmd /C \"{fullBatPath}\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    }
};
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/c991dc850604b3209f73eb43efea7afc8dfe7430/hybrids/.net/ProcessStartJS.bat) - a batch file wrapper of ProcessStartInfo:

```
C:\>ProcessStartJS.bat "cmd.exe" -arguments "/c pause" -style Minimized -priority High -newWindow yes -useshellexecute yes

Started: cmd.exe /c pause
PID:6540
```