# Launching a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have the following code:

```
String Antcbatchpath = @"C:\GUI\antc.bat";

System.Diagnostics.Process runantc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
runantc.StartInfo.FileName = Antcbatchpath;
runantc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
runantc.Start();
```

Will this load the batch file from `C:\GUI\antc.bat`?

Or `runantc.StartInfo.FileName` is only for a root directory? Root directory is where the application is located

EDIT 1:

hi instead of @"C:\GUI\antc.bat" i have a path:

```
String Antcbatchpath =@"C:\GUI Lab Tools\Build Machine\antc.bat";
```

which essentially contains white spaces. will it affect the `runantc.StartInfo.Filename = Antcbatchpath;` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use ProcessStartInfo to run a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382683/how-do-i-use-processstartinfo-to-run-a-batch-file)

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but just FYI there's some batch running info available on another [Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096591/how-to-hide-cmd-window-while-running-a-batch-file/1096626#1096626).

Answer (score 5):

`UseShellExecute = true` should do it.

Alternatively, if you need redirection, use:

```
runantc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
runantc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Antcbatchpath;
```

Comment: hi erik i need to direct it to write a text file for the error and outputs. can i still set useshellexecute to true?

Comment: Tells CMD to close after executing the batch file. You could use /K to execute the batch file but not exit CMD afterwards, but you need to pass either /C or /K to have the batch file executed.

Comment: i have a CMD.EXE & antc.bat in my C:\GUI\ so i should just use `runantc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE"` and `runantc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Antcbatchpath`

Comment: @jeremychan: yes. `CMD.EXE /C C:\GUI\antc.bat` would be the command, and that should work fine.

Comment: @erik i dont know why but even after i done that it is still not working. I am using wpf by the way. And using my orignal code as shown in my question, i dragged my application into the C:\GUI and it worked perfectly

Comment: @jeremychan: Replace \ with \\ in your string

Comment: hi erik, i think the problem lies with my white spaces. i dont think replacing \ with \\ in my string helps.. because i already put an "@" infront of the string. please clarify if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: oh so i have to add additional `'`?

Comment: @jeremychan: Yes, " or ' so that CMD sees your bat file name as one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `WorkingDirectory` to prevent any ambiguity, but in my experience, it is not necessary.

The problem you're having is because `antc.bat` is not an executable. It requires `UseShellExecute` to be true, but that would prevent you from redirecting the output. I guess you will have to choose either one.