# Warning in coded UI test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, exe, coded-ui-tests

I created a coded UI test project in Visual Studio 2012. When I run my test I get the following warning:

> "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
>   platform"

I think that this is because I have changed the `QTAgent32.exe.config` file, like is said on [Using Different Web Browsers with Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx).

To include screenshots in the coded UI logs, but after that I returned the default values in the exe file, but it still doesn't work.

Can somebody suggest me what to do?

Comment: Maybe you try to execute a non executable file.
look up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002995/execute-os-command-on-a-file-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You say you have changed everything back and it doesn't work now? I would either do a source control rollback if possible, or if not then:

- Create a new UI test project
- right click your old UI map and select 'View Code'. Copy the contents of this into your new UI map
- Open the new UI map in the normal view and save (this will update the generated code behind the scenes)
- Copy in your UI tests to the new project

You should now be able to run your tests with IE as in the default. At this point **take a backup** and then start changing one thing at once. Your issue is probably around the selenium integrations.

Is there a reason you are using this if you particularly want to do cross-browser testing rather than just using selenium direct? I love the coded ui tests but they aren't brilliant for multi-browser testing!