# The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform. Pythonplotter

Tags: c#, python, plot, operating-system, pythonplotter

I am trying to use the C# `pythonplotter` package, but when I compile [the example from github](https://github.com/IRC-SPHERE/PythonPlotter/blob/master/README.md) an error message shows up:

> Error in spawning plotting process: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

I am not sure what OS I need to use.

I currently use 64-bit Windows 10

Comment: The [RunPythonScript](https://github.com/IRC-SPHERE/PythonPlotter/blob/master/Utils.cs) method is `Process.Start()`ing the .py file itself. Windows can't do that (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002995/execute-os-command-on-a-file-c-sharp)), unless you change `UseShellExecute` to `true`, then `Process` asks Explorer, "Open this .py file with whatever the default program is". But you can't use `UseShellExecute=true` when redirecting stdout like they do. So you could try setting the startinfo to start Python itself and pass it arguments such that it runs the .py file. *shrug*

Comment: P.s., the main point is that the author has written and tested the program on linux: "Currently tested only on *nix platforms", which is why you are running into issues on Windows.

Comment: oh ok guys, thanks for the answer,  I desisted , but its good to know that now :)

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of that package. As mentioned in the comments, I've only tested this on linux and OS-X. I did plan to adapt it for Windows at some point. Please feel free to submit a pull request!