# Application Process.Start and WatchDog .net

Tags: .net, process, watchdog

i have some troubles with my application. It's a winForm app which has a this code :

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myfile.bat")
                                  {CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false};
            processInfo.Verb = "runas";
            var process1 = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process1.WaitForExit();
            process1.Close();
```

Now cause a bug in third party dll i need a watchdog to restart program when it crashes.

Now if i start the program manually i havent any problem but when the watchdog start my program it wont start myfile.bat.

It happen on Win7 And WinXp. I tried to disable UAC in Win7 but nothing.

I Used admin hidden account in xp and win7 too, but nothing. How could i fix this problem?

Comment: Can yuo explain what is this 'watchdog' ?

Comment: A program that check if your application is running or it's crashed , in this case the program try to start the application again.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I use ProcessStartInfo to run a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382683/how-do-i-use-processstartinfo-to-run-a-batch-file) suggests to use UseShellExecute = true, or else spawn cmd.exe with the batch file as a parameter.

Comment: already done. But it's not a bat problem. It a "right" problem i think with Windows. I mean the program is started from the another Program instead by me.