# The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd, startup, app-startup

I'm trying to add an application start task to unlock the ipSecurity section of the ApplicationHost.config file in my project. I have an cmd file located in /startup/startup.cmd. This is the contents of the file:

```
@echo off
@echo Installing "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Install-WindowsFeature Web-IP-Security"
@echo Unlocking configuration for "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
```

I've added this to application_start in Global.asax to run it:

```
var rootPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
var startupFilePath = String.Format("{0}startup\\startup.cmd", rootPath);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startupFilePath);
```

When I tried to load my site I got the error `The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You need to tell `Process` that you want to run a batch file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382683/how-do-i-use-processstartinfo-to-run-a-batch-file

Comment: I added UseShellExecute = true but it still didn't work. I also tried adding Verb = "runas" and got an "access denied" error